# PHP cURL login and loop through URLs stuck on first URL

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to loop through part numbers to get their associated information. If I echo the part number it is always the same. even though the starting part number is correct. Ideas?

```
include('./simple_html_dom.php');
require './includes/config.inc.php';
require './includes/Database.inc.php';


$db = new Database();

$db->query('SELECT part_num FROM GE LIMIT 4');
$results = $db->resultset();

foreach($results as $result){

$startingPN = trim($result['part_num']);

$curlPost['accountNumber']="*****";
$curlPost['password']="******";
$curlPost['contactForm']="https://www.*****.com/images/layout/input/submit.gif";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , "https://www.*****.com/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curlPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
$response = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.******.com/search/?part='.$startingPN); // set url for next request

$exec = curl_exec($ch);


// Create a DOM object
 $html = new simple_html_dom();
 // Load HTML from a string
 $html->load($exec);


    foreach($html->find('table.searchWholesale') as $article) {

        $item['part_num'] = $article->find('span.purpleBold', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['description'] = $article->find('span.twelve', 1)->plaintext;
        $item['cost'] = $article->find('span.fourteen', 1)->plaintext;
        $item['retail'] = $article->find('span.fourteen', 2)->plaintext;
        $item['brand'] = $article->find('td.leftColumn',0);
        $item['count'] = count($article->find('div.productHide'));
        $item['productHide1'] = $article->find('div.productHide', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['productHide2'] = $article->find('div.productHide', 1)->plaintext;

        $articles[] = $item;
    }
    
    $last_checked = date("U");
    $part_num = $articles[0]['part_num'];
    
   
        $title = ucwords(strtolower($articles[0]['description']));
        $cost = floatval(ltrim($articles[0]['cost'], '$'));
        $retail = floatval(ltrim($articles[0]['retail'], '$'));
        $brand = $articles[0]['brand'];
        $brand->children(0)->outertext = "";
        $brand->children(1)->outertext = "";
        $brand->children(2)->outertext = "";
        $brand->children(3)->outertext = "";
        $brand->children(4)->outertext = "";
        $brand->children(5)->outertext = "";
        $brand->children(6)->outertext = "";
        //$brand->children(7)->outertext = "";
        //$brand->children(8)->outertext = "";
        //$brand->children(9)->outertext = "";

        $brand_qty = explode(" ", $brand);
        $name_brand =  $brand_qty[15];
        $qty_avail = $brand_qty[21];

        echo '<br>'.$startingPN . '<br>' . $part_num . '<br>' . $title . '<br>' . $cost . '<br>' . $retail  . '<br>' . $name_brand;
}
```

This outputs... The first one is the only one that is correct. NOTICE WE04X10010 is being echoed as the part number in all subsequent  loops.

```
WE04X10010
WE04X10010
Buzzer
55.5
103.58
General

WD12X441 <-($startingPN)
WE04X10010 <- THIS SHOULD BE THE SAME AS $startingPN (WD12X44)
Buzzer
55.5
103.58
General

WH11X139 <-($startingPN)
WE04X10010 <- THIS SHOULD BE THE SAME AS $startingPN (WH11X139)
Buzzer
55.5
103.58
General

WH11X10015 <-($startingPN)
WE04X10010 <- THIS SHOULD BE THE SAME AS $startingPN (WH11X10015)
Buzzer
55.5
103.58
General
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your $articles variable need to reset in each master loop. Like below:

```
$articles = [];
foreach($html->find('table.searchWholesale') as $article) {

        $item['part_num'] = $article->find('span.purpleBold', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['description'] = $article->find('span.twelve', 1)->plaintext;
        $item['cost'] = $article->find('span.fourteen', 1)->plaintext;
        $item['retail'] = $article->find('span.fourteen', 2)->plaintext;
        $item['brand'] = $article->find('td.leftColumn',0);
        $item['count'] = count($article->find('div.productHide'));
        $item['productHide1'] = $article->find('div.productHide', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['productHide2'] = $article->find('div.productHide', 1)->plaintext;

        $articles[] = $item;
    }
```

Comment: You were sort of right or atleast gave me a path to an idea. I ended up adding $articles = array(); just below the initial foreach. If I added it as you posted I got a fatal error. But it give me a starting point. TY!

Comment: Glad it help. This syntax supported in `PHP >= 5.4`